# Postman post request cannot read property of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I have a route setup in my express server which sends a post request and adds a new message o my mongoDB database.

When I statically add names to the body fields; i.e `new userMessage =  new Message({ name: 'Joseph', email: 'joseph@gmail.com', message: 'Hello Joseph'})`, it posts successfully.

But when it is dynamic; i.e `new userMessage =  new Message({ name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, message: req.body.message})` it throws an error.

I have tried several times to debug the issue with no success.

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at router.post (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\routes\message.js:13:24)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at cors (C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Hackathons\hack.api\app\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)
```

**Message.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MessageSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    message: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = Message = mongoose.model('message', MessageSchema);
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

const message =  require('../routes/message');

const app = express();

//Enable cors
app.use(cors( {origin: '*' }));

//Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/messages', { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

//Use routes
app.use('/message', message);

//Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Test route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world');
})

//Set server port
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

**message.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Load message model
const Message = require('../models/Message');

router.get('/test', (req, res) =>
    res.json({ msg: 'Message post route works' })
);

router.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    const userMessage = new Message({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        message: req.body.message
    });

    userMessage.save()
        .then(message => res.json(message))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by changing

```
//Use routes
app.use('/message', message);

//Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

to

```
//Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Use routes
app.use('/message', message);
```

I guess the order matters. In server configuration order really is important.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to get your data and validate it before creating new Mongo object:

```
const { body: {name, email, message } } = req;
//validate email for example or you just logs it to know data reviced or not? 
const userMessage = new Message({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        message: message
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending nested objects from client side like `person[name] = 'cw'` then you have to write `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` or if that is not the case,make sure your input in the html form has the `name="file"` attribute.